# Silverlight: How to apply ScaleTransform to a Ellipse but not the StrokeThickness

Tags: silverlight

I have to show some circles with scale function, but I need the strokethickness stay the same. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

```
<Grid x:Name="SelectedPanel"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform
            ScaleX="{Binding some binding}"
            ScaleY="{Binding some binding}"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Ellipse
        Stroke="#09C900"
        StrokeThickness="3"
        StrokeDashArray="5 2"
        StrokeDashOffset="6"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you apply the ScaleTransform to the Ellipse the StrokeThickness will grow with the rest of the element.
I suggest you manipulate Width and Height of the Ellipse instead.
Something like this...

```
<Ellipse
    Stroke="#09C900"
    StrokeThickness="3"
    StrokeDashArray="5 2"
    StrokeDashOffset="6"
    Width="{some binding}"
    Height="{some binding}"/>
```